# The output negative pole (-) of my PSU is connected to protective earth. Why doesn't it trigger the GFCI?

Tags: gfci

I am living in Europe and the power plug ([Schuko plug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schuko)) of my PC PSU has 3 pins.

These pins are the positive pole (+), the negative pole (-) and protective earth (PE pin).

Please let me say in a few sentence what I learned so you perhaps can find an error.

First I want to say that the negative pole and PE are not the same. As far as I know, the PE line goes into the ground on the property of the house. While the negative pole (-) goes back into the transformer of the energy company.

The negative pole is most often 0V compared to earth but it can have a different potential.

I want to add that even if you connect the negative pole (-) to PE it will blow out the [GFCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device) (as it's said in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVC9DNMRrIs) video).

Now I wonder that my multimeter says that the output negative pole (-) is connected to protective earth (PE) directly.

Because I learned that if there flows current from (-) or (+) to PE it should blow out the GFCI. I learned that there never flows current from or to PE.

I chcked 3 PSUs and it's always like that.

What am I missing?

[image: PSU]

Comment: The pins on your mains schuko plug are not "positive pole (+), the negative pole (-)". AC mains supply has a live/line/hot pole and a neutral pole, neither one of which is "positive" or "negative". The neutral pole will be connected to the PE at some point in the system, depending on the grounding topology in your country, In an isolated power supply as you have there, there is no point where the DC negative output pole is in any way connected to the input neutral pole *in the PSU unit*. As such, there is no reason for the GFCI to detect any fault (in normal operation).

Comment: Could you show exactly what the white connector is connected to?

Comment: @brhans Current flows from the positive DC pole into PE (negative DC). Doesn't that trigger the GFCI?

Comment: @jonathanjo I'd to open the PSU. Perhaps I can do that tomorrow...

Comment: What makes you believe current flows into the PE?

Comment: The negative pole of the power supply is at the same potential as PE, but that doesn't make it the same exact thing as PE.

Comment: there is a transformer providing isolation between mains and DC.